# Missing "curl" tool. Unable to download Dart SDK. Consider running "sudo apt-get install curl"

Tags: android, curl, flutter, dart

I facing this issue in flutter after adding dependency s`hared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4` in `pubspec.yaml` file.

After added the dependency, it suggest me to update flutter sdk for use the version of the dependency. So I just run `flutter upgrade`. After that I'm not able to run the application and for every command (`Flutter upgrade`, `Flutter doctor` etc), throws the below error.

> Missing "curl" tool. Unable to download Dart SDK. Consider running
>   "sudo apt-get install curl".
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I also run command `sudo apt-get install curl` and get below result.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please guide me to get out of the problem.

Comment: Have you got any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just open your terminal (if Ubuntu). Then type

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then try to upgrade the **Flutter Sdk**. it will work.
NB: Before upgrading, you must take a backup of your present code. Or some API may show as deprecated and that will affect your project.

Answer (score 0):

just go the place you install flutter and delete the flutter that you downloaded and download a new one the error will go